# Why are there so many accounts of the Hebrews' killing their neighbors and so few of their being kind or good?

Tags: tanach

I know everybody was attacking everybody in those days, but still why are there so few examples of the Hebrews setting an example of kindness to the poor, weak or even being kind? Instead, the solution to every problem seems to be just kill them. For example:

- The Amalekite genocide (I Samuel 15:2-3)
- Jephthah sacrifices his daughter to God as a burned offering to pay him back for helping him slaughter 20 cities (Judges 11:39)
- An angel killed 185,000 sleeping soldiers (II Kings 19:34, Isaiah 37:36)
- Samson kills 3000 people (Judges 16:27-30)
- Samson kills 1000 men with the jawbone of an ass (Judges 15:14-15)
- God stops the sun so Joshua can kill in the daylight (Joshua 10:10-11)

http://dwindlinginunbelief.blogspot.com/2010/04/gods-top-50-killings-how-do-you-rate.html

Why is the Bible so full of hatred and killing but not kindness?

Comment: You equate killing with hate, but this is often not the case in these Biblical accounts. They are looked upon not as good events, but as necessary ones, each for its own reason. Besides for the fact that it is never wise to judge the societies of other times or places, the Torah seems to see killing as sometimes necessary, or even in some cases, a kindness to the victim.

Comment: @rudolph34, if you actually read the bible instead of a hateful website, you might find that Amalek was continuously attacking and killing Hebrews with no reason, Jephtah did not sacrifice his daughter as a burnt offering, the angel (which is not a Hebrew) killed only a portion of a massive army about to attack the Hebrews, and that Samson was avenging a 40 year subjugation.  You will also find many acts of kindness and laws obliging Hebrews to be kind, which, of course is not brought on that site.

Comment: Voting to reopen. While I dislike the phrasing of this question and its total lack of research, I think that it should be answered and refuted, because there are many who _do_ believe these things, erroneously.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, I think it is important to point out that the Bible is **not** a book of *history* - it is a book of *morality*. Any story presented therein is intended not to relate that which was, but to teach a lesson on *what should be*. Some of the stories of cruelty (not in the list you mentioned) are there to teach what NOT to do.

Comment: I don't know why this got so many downvotes I think it is a very good question and in some ways want to ask the same. I don't agree with all his examples. Samson killing 30 philistines to get their garments to pay off his lost bet and King David killing them to get foreskins are better examples.

Comment: Mass murder of Shechem is rebuked. Levi though seems to end up as the leader of the tribe that stands for peace.

Comment: Mass murder of Cheshbon (Sichon) and Bashan (Og) killing every resident, including women and children. Mass murder of Midian other than virgin females. Mass murder of Jericho killing every resident except Rachav and her family. Mass murder of Ai in avengence of losing a battle where the people were only defending themselves.

Comment: We even mass-murder our own: Mass murder of Binyamin including all the women (and children) and all of Yabesh Gilad other than 400 virgins.

Comment: Amalek we know about. Vengence for an attack on the Jewish people about 400 years earlier. That's like us going into Spain now and mass-murdering them because of the inquisition or mass-murdering Germans in the 24th century because of the holocaust.

Comment: King David certainly did have blood on his hands. 200 Philistines to get foreskins to marry Michal (Samuel I, 18:27) but more so 27:8-9. 
Of course we know about Saul and Doeg murdering the people of Nov but Doeg did lose olam-haba over it so it seemed to have been punished.

Answer (score 4):

Abraham and Sara set an example how to take care of guests. Jews are required to tithe their earnings to help the poor. Moses did all he could to help the Jews get out of Egypt, and to save them when they sinned. The Torah is not fiction, it is true facts. Yes there were times that Jews killed, however it was their enemies that they killed. The Torah commands us that if someone tries to kill us, we should kill them first, and most of the examples that you bring are of people that fit this command. In addition these accounts are to remind us that God stands by our side if we do what is right, even if we are the minority.